# IBM MQ Logging All Messages to All Topics

Tags: ibm-mq

I want to set up a windows service that logs all messages to all topics in my system. It seems like the way the code is working in C# means that I need to create a root topic "MyCompany" and then subscribe to the "#" wildcard topic name of the "MyCompany" topic object. This will allow me to log all messages so long as I force all applications in my company to publish to topics within the "MyCompany" topic then set up my logger to subscribe like this:

`_topic = _queueManager.AccessTopic("#", "MyCompany", MQC.MQTOPIC_OPEN_AS_SUBSCRIPTION, _openOptions);`

Is there a way to set IBM MQ up so that I don't need to force the use of the MyCompany root topic? Do I need to access the topic a different way in my code?

Answer (score 2):

You are overthinking it.  Or maybe you are confused by the terminology and think you need both a Topic String and Topic Object.  Not so.

You can specify:

- Only a Topic String
- Only a Topic Object
- Both.

Note: A Topic Object is also called an administrative Topic.  And in some IBM documentation, it is called Topic Name.  Not very consistent but it is something you should be aware of.

So, the easiest way to do it is:

```
_topic = _queueManager.AccessTopic("#", null, MQC.MQTOPIC_OPEN_AS_SUBSCRIPTION, _openOptions);
```

This call will subscribe to all topics of the queue manager.  See [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=interfaces-mqqueuemanagernet-class) for more information about the AccessTopic method.

Comment: Does this pick up the activity trace publications?   That would be my only concern with 9.0 and higher.

Comment: This will not pick up any topic defined with WILDCARD(BLOCK). That is, after all, the exact purpose of WILDCARD(BLOCK). If you want to change this attribute then you could, but the reason they have that setting by default is because you'd not be expected to want to include them.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize you could pass null in as TopicObject- the API would make more sense if the methods were overloaded. And if there was better documentation. In case someone else finds this, it took me a while to figure out how to set the authorization properly for wildcards likes this. Use setmqaut with ** for the topic name: ```setmqaut -m [q manager name] -n  ** -t topic -p [username]+pub +sub```

Comment: Wildcarding in IBM MQ is a little different.  A single asterisk ('*') means to match only on the current level.  Two asterisks ('**') means to match on all levels.  By levels, I mean something like 'test/ABC/one/' for topics has 3 levels and 'TEST.HR.Q01' for queues has 3 levels.  So, '*' means match on the 1st level.  i.e. 'test' for topics or 'TEST' for queues.

Comment: @Roger Thanks. The '**' is what I wanted. The big jump was figuring out that I need to use that instead of the '#' at the commandline.